# how to access index of the test in pytest.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

These decorators make 6 tests:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", [2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("z", [4, 5])
```

How inspect pytest to get current index or some ID of the test, inside the test body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found it:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [pytest.param(0, id="first_test"), 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", [2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("z", [4, 5])
def test_it(request, x, y, z):
    if request.node.nodename == "test_it[first_test]":
        # something special
```

Comment: `request.node.nodename` throws  "AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'nodename'" for pytest 6.2.4
It was changed to: `request.node.name`

Comment: Still no real answer since 2019?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define `id` explicitly then you could probably use:

```py
current_input_id = int(request.node.name.split('[')[-1].split(']')[0][-1])
```

Comment: It would be good to confirm your answer works by including a small example.  Currently a suggestion like this is more suitable as a comment, not an answer.